# Confused about the indexPath struct in Swift for Table Views

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Can someone please explain how IndexPath works in swift?

With the help of an array, I am able to place each object in the visible rows of the table view. But I don't understand how index path is able to do so.

Comment: You can give more details about your question? What do you mean with: "I am able to place each object in the visible row"?

Comment: The tableView manages the displaying of the data by asking its delegate for the data for each visible row one at a time.  The indexPath specifies the particular row in the particular section that it needs.  You use the indexPath.row to return the right piece of data to display for that row.